# F-N Shortcuts in the Windows' Command Prompt

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, command-prompt

Where can I get some explanations on what <kbd>F1</kbd> , <kbd>F2</kbd> , <kbd>F3</kbd> ,<kbd>F4</kbd> , <kbd>F5</kbd> , <kbd>F6</kbd> , <kbd>F7</kbd> , <kbd>F8</kbd> , <kbd>F9</kbd> , <kbd>F10</kbd> , <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> do in Windows' Command Prompt?

Are there some other useful shortcuts for Windows' Command Prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the function keys used by the old MS-DOS DosKey command. They are now built into Windows NT's command interpeter. Go to `Start > Help and Support` and search for `DosKey`.

See Doskey at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490894.aspx.